# Is it possible to conform to StringLiteralConvertible with an enum?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

When attempting to adopt StringLiteralConvertible in an enum like so:

```
enum Component: StringLiteralConvertible {
    case Static(String)
    case AnyInt

    typealias ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType = String
    typealias UnicodeScalarLiteralType = String

    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: UnicodeScalarLiteralType) {
    }
    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType) {
    }
    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Variable 'self' used before initialized
```

in each of the initializers.

According to [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/), the correct way to conform to that protocol involves overriding a class func that takes a string literal and returns an object of the desired class/struct. Like this:

```
static func convertFromStringLiteral(value: String) -> CGPoint {
    return NSPointFromString(value) // CGPointFromString on iOS
}
```

Has that changed in a semi-recent Swift update? Is it possible to adopt StringLiteralConvertible as an enum?

Comment: Swift `init` methods normally don't require setting `self` (as you would in Objective-C), but `enum` `init` methods are a special case. See @MartinR's answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `StringLiteralConvertible` protocol has changed and the `convertFromStringLiteral`
function does not exist anymore.

You already have the required initializers. The error is that you don't assign a value to `self`. Example implementation:

```
enum Component: StringLiteralConvertible {
    case Static(String)
    case AnyInt

    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self = Static(value)
    }

    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self = Static(value)
    }

    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self = Static(value)
    }
}

let comp : Component = "Foo"
```

---

**Swift 3/4 update:**

```
enum Component: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    case `static`(String)
    case anyInt

    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self = .static(value)
    }
}

let comp: Component = "Foo"
```